# What versions of iOS are on most devices? What iOS versions should a developer target?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

According to [Chitka](http://www.tuaw.com/2013/02/13/chitika-all-versions-of-ios-6-now-account-for-83-1-of-ios-traf/), "All versions of iOS 6 now account for 83.1% of iOS traffic"

> all versions of iOS 6 (6.0, 6.1.0, 6.1.1) now account for 83.1 percent
>   of all iOS traffic, only about 12.2 percent of all iOS users are still
>   on iOS 5, approximately 5 percent of total iOS users are using earlier
>   versions of iOS.

The data uses traffic data gathered on February 11 2013. How accurate is this data and more importantly for developers, What iOS versions should a developer target? Is there any reason to care about iOS 4 and below?

Comment: http://david-smith.org/iosversionstats/ is a pretty good page for stats, it'll allow you to make your own decision.

Comment: As of now, you can only create an app that supports 4.3 or later so there is no need to even think about anything before that.

Comment: The answer is a moving target -- adoption rates for newer versions increase constantly as people get around to upgrading old devices or buying new ones, even newer OS versions are introduced, etc. You need to figure out how much benefit you get for supporting old versions compared to saved work and simpler code you get from not supporting them, and different people will make that judgement differently. This question should therefore be closed as either 'not constructive' or 'too localized.' It's not a bad question, just one we can't answer for you.

Comment: For more on why questions like this might not work so well here, see my Meta question ["How do we deal with a recurring question like OS install base statistics?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72954/how-do-we-deal-with-a-recurring-question-like-os-install-base-statistics). Answers to questions like this are only valid for very short periods of time.

Answer (score 1):

No you can just go with **iOS 5** and above. I am targeting **iOS 5** and above for every app. There is no need to target **iOS 4**. Infact i have some of my apps on itunes targeting iOS 5 and above. And they are going perfectly on app store. :)

Comment: I would add that you should only support iOS 5.1 and later. Any device with 5.0 can be updated to at least 5.1. There are too many bugs in iOS 5.0 and a few important API changes were made in 5.1.

Comment: @rmaddy is there any bud in ios6.0?

Comment: @Rajneesh071 Of course. There are bugs in every version of iOS.

Comment: i have ios 5.1.1 and 6.0, what should i do, i can't update 5.1.1